# Extjs Store listener

Tags: extjs

My store function was working efficiently on extjs 6.0, but when migrated to extjs 6.7 its showing error

```
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
            model: 'User',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : '../ROOT/customHeader/configs/customHeaderConfig.json',
                reader: 
                {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: "custom"
                }
            },
            autoLoad:true,
            listeners : {
                load : function(thisObj, records){
                    var logo_src = records[0].get("viewer_logo_src");
                    panObj.getComponent('header_toolbar').getComponent('headerLogo').setSrc(logo_src);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: not getting the error message...records does not have any value fetched

Comment: I suppose you can reach `load`. Add a breakpoint and see the values of your parameters. From the documentation `load ( this, records, successful, operation, eOpts )`. Check that your `json` file actually returns data from `network in chrome`